# Why does this code "backpack.unshift("Rock")" at a specific part of my code not unshift() "Rock" in my backpack array?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to ask is this: I have this command in the program called `backpack.unshift("Rock");` and it should activate when I type ";m", and when I type in ";b" and press the "enter" button, it doesn't unshift() the "Rock". The if statement works fine, and when i put `backpack.unshift("Rock");`before the `if (textBox == ";mine" || textBox == ";m")`, the code unshifts the "Rock" into my backpack array. Why does this unshift code not work when I put it after the if statement for the "mine" command?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function ask() {
  var textBox = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var enter = document.getElementById("submit");
  var backpack = [];
  if (textBox == ";backpack" || textBox == ";b") {
    alert(backpack);
  } else if(textBox == ";mine" || textBox == ";m") {
    backpack.unshift("Rock");
    alert("you have mined 1 rock! Adding to bag...");
    } else {alert("This isn't a command");
    }
  }
</script>
<title>
The Game
</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="text" type=text/> <input id="submit" type=button value="Enter" onclick="ask();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every time `ask()` is called, you are creating a new `var backpack`. That should probably be a global variable instead, so it persists across function calls.

Comment: Thanks! You have fixed my problem. Now I know that a variable I want to keep as one variable should be a global one.

Comment: @MadMaxPlayz: not necessarily global. Creating tons of global variables can be it's own headache. Ideally, what you probably want is a global object to hold your state variables.

Comment: Oh. Ok then. I will keep that in mind too! Thanks.